# Positioning a claim in an html-email below all content

Tags: css, positioning, html-email

I have got a Problem with genreated Contentent in Emails that in some cases overlaps a signature we want to put below email content:

```
<div style="height: 200px; background-color: green;">
    much Content in here
    <div style="background-color: red; height: 400px; width:100px;">
        Some generated Content here
    </div>
</div>
<div id="companyclaim">
    Take a quick look at  
    <b>
        <a href="http://example.com">
            example.com - just awesome
        </a>
    </b>
</div>
```

Is there any way to have the "companyclaim" below all the other content. I see it is below the 200px div, but the inner 400px div overlaps it, what causes the claim to be right "in" the inner div.

i tried a table, but with the same effect. Position fixed did neither work as you could imagine.

I created a fiddle to take a quick look: http://jsfiddle.net/tavKD/1/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/tavKD/3/

do not put height to the green div

```
<div style=" background-color: green;">
    much Content in here
    <div style="background-color: red; height: 400px; width:100px;">
        Some generated Content here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is that i do not have any influence to the content of the emails, i could be generated by different generators and edited after that. i do only have the resulting html and i ran into some constructs like this, so i hoped to find a way to avoid my element beiing overlaped generally so i do not disturb the content and in best case the message is always visible

Comment: one idea would be to wrap the generated content in another container... but if they decide to use absolute positions or other funky html structure, the wrapper may not always capture the total height of the generated content

Comment: I tried it with a table around but this did not work either http://jsfiddle.net/devinator2000/T63WX/